# How do i fix this error ? android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11

Tags: android, xml

Hello all my activity wont start for some reason and Im having trouble figuring it out, its a simple app it starts and shows this layout, but i keep getting errors everytime i start it and i dont know why

xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/back">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnTraining"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/play" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnExercises"
                    android:text="Exercises"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    app:buttonColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:shadowEnabled="true"
                    app:cornerRadius="2dp"
                    app:shadowHeight="2dp" />

                <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnSetting"
                    android:text="Setting"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    app:buttonColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:shadowEnabled="true"
                    app:cornerRadius="2dp"
                    app:shadowHeight="2dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                android:id="@+id/btnCalender"
                android:text="Calender"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:buttonColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:shadowEnabled="true"
                app:cornerRadius="0dp"
                app:shadowHeight="2dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Java code

```
    package com.example.kishorsinh.yogaapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Button btnExercises,btnSetting,btnCalender;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



        btnExercises =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnExercises);
        btnExercises.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,ListExercises.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_activity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        //if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            //return true;
       // }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_instructions) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_benefits) {

        }else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kishorsinh.yogaapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //Library
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'


}
```

Gradle version
3.1.3

Error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.kishorsinh.yogaapp/com.example.kishorsinh.yogaapp.HomeActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML
>   file line #36: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1011)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1011)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>           at com.example.kishorsinh.yogaapp.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:26)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6956)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
>        Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 1 to color: type=0x5
>           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:480)
>           at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
>           at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.(FButton.java:52)
>             ... 37 more

Comment: can you post your java code along with imports, It seems like you might be missing them.

Comment: @KaranMer Updated

Comment: What your gradle version and how you add this dependency in your app level gradle file? There is something wrong with that library. you can use this one https://github.com/jd-alexander/android-flat-button

Comment: https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button/issues/41 have a look!

Comment: try adding a new color value in color xml with name as `fbutton_default_color` and also add `fbutton_default_shadow_color`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve this errors by changing libraries

`implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'` to

```
implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'
```

and make changes in xml files

```
app:buttonColor="@color/colorPrimary"
```

to `app:fButtonColor="@color/colorPrimary"` to all projects by

> buttonColor

to

> fButtonColor

.

Answer (score 0):

May be you didn't add following dependency in app gradle :
        compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'

Answer (score 0):

remove this

implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'

```
<info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCalender"
            android:text="Calender"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:buttonColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:cornerRadius="0dp"
            app:shadowHeight="2dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

May Be you're having problem in your `color.xml` file

From your error log

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert
>   value at index 1 to color: type=0x5 at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:480) at

At first , It seems like your color value is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had also a similar error when I deleted an old fragment layout XML file and added a new fragment file but I didn't update the **activity_main.xml**. The problem was in `android: name` property of fragment and I updated that and it worked out.